# Why can't a read-write user see the aspnet_ tables after I've created them with aspnet_regsql?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, membership-provider, aspnetdb

I created the membership tables etc. with aspnet_regsql -S myServer -E -A mr -d anExistingDatabase. I can see these changes in SQL Server Management Studio, when I connect as myself through Windows Authentication.

I could not see these changes in SQL Server Management Studio, while logged in as a readwrite user. I cannot make the appropriate changes in Visual Studio 2008 [Project/ASP.NET Configuration] either. When I click on the Security link in ASP.NET Web Application Administration I get the following error:

> "There is a problem with your selected
>   data store. This can be caused by an
>   invalid server name or credentials, or
>   by insufficient permission. It can
>   also be caused by the role manager
>   feature not being enabled. Click the
>   button below to be redirected to a
>   page where you can choose a new data
>   store."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely the issue is one of permissions.  Go look at your user and grant it the appropriate rights.

To test this, you can grant it full dbo rights to the database.  Once the user can see all the tables, take away dbo and apply the rights it really should have.

Comment: Thanks. There were a lot of new membership roles added under security. I had to add a few of the aspnet_* permissions to the service account.